# Align image right without maxwidth

Tags: html, css, image

[What I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ncrH.png)

Hi there, I'm trying to make some admission tickets using PHP. I want the QR code to align to the right of the title text. Problem is, it always goes to the far right of the screen. Since the title might change for different formats, I can't just hardcode an absolute position or use a max-width property on the entire div.

Here is my HTML

```html
<div class= "content"  ID ="carte" style=" padding:0;">
    <div  style="  text-align: left; font-weight:bolder; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;">
    <img src="logovoltaic.png" height = 50 align = "left" style="padding-right:10px"/>
        <div class="" style=" overflow:hidden; align:center;font-size: 38px; padding-left:20px; padding-top: 5px;  overflow:visible;">Carte d'enregistrement <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="   padding:0;font-size: 20px; padding-top: 5; vertical-align: top; font-weight:bold; align:left;">
    Veuillez présenter cette carte à votre arrivée en studio
    </div>
    <div style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 10px; vertical-align: top; font-weight:regular;float:left">
    Nom: <?= isset($_GET['prenominput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['prenominput']) : ''; ?> <?= isset($_GET['prenominput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['nominput']) : ''; ?><br>
    Adresse courriel: <?= isset($_GET['courrielinput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['courrielinput']) : ''; ?><br>
    Identifiant: <?= isset($_GET['matriculeinput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['matriculeinput']) : ''; ?>

    </div>



    <div style=" padding:10;font-size: 30px; padding-top: 0; margin-right: 0px;vertical-align: top; font-weight:bolder;" align = "right">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET["matriculeinput"])){
        generate();



        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <button type="button" name="button" class= "button" onclick="collapseme('carte');collapseme('formulaire')">Éditer vos informations</button>
</div>
```

the generate() function simply echoes the QR code image. meanwhile the "collapseme()" function is just a way to show/hide parts of the page depending on what step the user is at.

Comment: you should use class or ids instead inline style, it'sa mess to keep update. If you have a title, use hx tag, you can even set your qr code in it ahead the text and float it right if your into old ways of coding ;) It will work and be understood everywhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class= "content"  ID ="carte" style=" padding:0;">
    <div  style="  text-align: left; font-weight:bolder; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;">
    <img src="logovoltaic.png" height = 50 align = "right" style="padding-right:10px"/>
        <div class="" style=" overflow:hidden; align:center;font-size: 38px; padding-left:20px; padding-top: 5px;  overflow:visible;">Carte d'enregistrement <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="   padding:0;font-size: 20px; padding-top: 5; vertical-align: top; font-weight:bold; align:left;">
    Veuillez présenter cette carte à votre arrivée en studio
    </div>
    <div style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 10px; vertical-align: top; font-weight:regular;float:left">
    Nom: <?= isset($_GET['prenominput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['prenominput']) : ''; ?> <?= isset($_GET['prenominput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['nominput']) : ''; ?><br>
    Adresse courriel: <?= isset($_GET['courrielinput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['courrielinput']) : ''; ?><br>
    Identifiant: <?= isset($_GET['matriculeinput']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['matriculeinput']) : ''; ?>

    </div>



    <div style=" padding:10;font-size: 30px; padding-top: 0; margin-right: 0px;vertical-align: top; font-weight:bolder;" align = "right">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET["matriculeinput"])){
        generate();



        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <button type="button" name="button" class= "button" onclick="collapseme('carte');collapseme('formulaire')">Éditer vos informations</button>
</div>
```

Only change image tag property align left to right(**align = "right"**)